# azure data flow convert string json array to json array

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using azure data flow, and I want to pass a json array inside an at() function like this :
[image]

the error is :

> At function takes an array or a map for the first parameter.

urls value is :

> [{"url":"http://url1.com"},{"url":"http://url2.com"},{"url":"http://url3.com"},{"url":"http://url4.com"}]

why it consider urls value as a string ?

Comment: Look in the Inspect tab on that transformation in your graph. What is ADF showing as the data type for the "urls" column?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to an array using the `Derived column` transformation.

1. In a `Derived Column`, first **replace** square brackets with empty/blank and with **split** function, split the string based on the delimiter **comma** (,).

[image]

**Derived Column preview:**

[image]

2. Now you can use this array in the **at()** function in your expression.

[image]

Comment: OMG: There is no better way for doing this?